# Repeating a flag until it changes to a different status

Tags: sql-server, business-intelligence

**The input data is in this format**

```
case_id    new_value    old_value   start_date   end_date

aaa        status1      null        2017-01-01   2017-01-03
aaa        status2      status1     2017-01-04   2017-01-06
aaa        status3      status2     2017-01-07   2017-01-08
aaa        closed       status3     2017-01-09   null
```

**Current Query**

```
select 
     case_id
    ,snapshot_date
    ,max(cast(is_status1 as int))
    ,max(cast(is_status2 as int))
    ,max(cast(is_status3 as int))
    (
    select * from 
   (select  
    c.case_id,
    cast(pp.start_date as date) as snapshot_date, 
    case when pp.new_value  like 'Closed%' then 1 else 0 end                    as is_closed,  -- 0 as is_closed
    case when pp.new_value  = 'status1' then 1 else 0 end             as is_status1,
    case when pp.new_value  = 'Status2' then 1 else 0 end       as is_status2,
    case when pp.new_value  = 'status3' then 1 else 0 end              as is_status3
    from [case] c 
    left join CaseEvent pp  on (c.case_id=pp.case_id)
    where event_start_date is not null )t 
    where 
    (  is_status1 =1
    or is_status2= 1
    or is_status3 = 1  
    )
    )t
    group by case_id,snapshot_date;
```

**Output**

```
id       snapshot_date is_created is_closed is_status1  is_status2  is_status3 

aaa      2017-01-01       1          0          1           0           0          
aaa      2017-01-02       0          0          0           0           0          
aaa      2017-01-03       0          0          0           0           0          
aaa      2017-01-04       0          0          0           1           0          
aaa      2017-01-05       0          0          0           0           0          
aaa      2017-01-06       0          0          0           0           0          
aaa      2017-01-07       0          0          0           0           1          
aaa      2017-01-08       0          0          0           0           0          
aaa      2017-01-09       0          1          0           0           0
```

It means, a case aaa is created and changes status1 on 2017-01-01 and it stays in that state until it changes to status2 on 2017-01-04. And again it stays in that status till it changes to status3 on 2017-01-07. And then it continues till it closes on 2017-01-09.

Requirement: I need the flag '1' to repeat on to the other dates until the status is changed again.

**Desired Output**

```
case_id  snapshot_date is_created is_closed is_status1  is_status2  is_status3 

aaa      2017-01-01       1          0          1           0           0          
aaa      2017-01-02       0          0          1           0           0          
aaa      2017-01-03       0          0          1           0           0          
aaa      2017-01-04       0          0          0           1           0          
aaa      2017-01-05       0          0          0           1           0          
aaa      2017-01-06       0          0          0           1           0          
aaa      2017-01-07       0          0          0           0           1          
aaa      2017-01-08       0          0          0           0           1          
aaa      2017-01-09       0          1          0           0           0
```

Comment: Isn't this an indictment of the process that writes those rows in the first place? Shouldn't that process understand that it needs to preserve the flags until the next status change?

Comment: No  putting data is this format has been done by me.

Comment: What have you tried?  Show your efforts please, we're not a code writing service.

Comment: From my perspective, with what little information I have here, you have told me that you are in control of how the data are inserted to the table, so *why are you inserting incorrect data into the table*? Why didn't you insert with the appropriate is_status flag in the first place? What is your actual goal? Are you trying to correct data that has been inserted incorrectly in the first place? You need to shore up both ends: the existing data and the new data. If your insert process keeps inserting rows in the incorrect status then *the bug is in your insert process.*

Comment: Whatever inserts snapshot records or whatever you call these should *determine what the status for the previous snapshot date was* and then toggle that status on the row it is inserting if all statuses are currently off.

Comment: Please read the entire question again. I am not inserting wrong data. I have done some edits to the question.

Comment: When you say things like "I have managed to put my data like this..." *No one understands what you mean.* I believe you have a table that has those rows in it. Do you? If you do, then it is absolutely whatever inserted those rows that is wrong and needs to be trained to do the correct thing. Show me your code or I'm done.

Comment: Yeah, I do not have a table. I have a query which results the data in this format. And I am trying hard to think if there is anyway I can get the output what I want.

Comment: Youre going to need to show some code or no one is going to be able to help, because I legitimately do not understand your data, how it is stored, etc.

Comment: Yep, just updated..

Comment: Given your sample data in your top, original, table. What is the "Status" between 1/3 and 1/6 (between status 1 ending and status 2 beginning)?

Comment: @JNevill I believe there is a typo there and the second row is supposed to be 01-04-2017 start date, so the status from 1/1 to 1/3 is 1 and the status from 1/4 to1/6 is 2.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I fixed that.

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try:

```
declare @data table (case_id varchar(10), new_value varchar(10), old_value varchar(10), start_date date, end_date date)

insert into @data
values ('aaa','status1',null,'2017-01-01','2017-01-03'),
       ('aaa','status2','status1','2017-01-04','2017-01-06'),
       ('aaa','status3','status2','2017-01-07','2017-01-08'),
       ('aaa','closed','status3','2017-01-09',null)

;with drange as
(
    select case_id, min(start_date) dstart, max(start_date) as dend
    from @data
    group by case_id
), dates as
    (
        select case_id, dstart, dend
        from drange
        union all
        select case_id, dateadd(day,1,dstart), dend
        from dates
        where dstart<dend
    )

select d1.case_id, 
       d2.dstart as snapshot_date, 
       case when d1.new_value = 'status1' and (d1.start_date=d2.dstart) then 1 else 0 end as is_created,
       case when d1.new_value = 'closed' then 1 else 0 end as is_closed,
       case when d1.new_value = 'status1' then 1 else 0 end as is_status1,
       case when d1.new_value = 'status2' then 1 else 0 end as is_status2,
       case when d1.new_value = 'status3' then 1 else 0 end as is_status3
from @data d1
join dates d2 on d1.case_id=d2.case_id and d2.dstart between d1.start_date and isnull(d1.end_date,d1.start_date)
order by d1.case_id, d2.dstart
```